# Outlook VBA Pickfolder command to include subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm currently using the following code to bring back a count of how many e-mails are in each category in Outlook (code is in Excel). However it doesn't take into account any subfolders. Could you help me change the pickfolder to also select any subfolders?

```
Sub test()
Dim oDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim olItem As Object
Dim arrData() As Variant
Dim CategoryCnt As Integer
Dim c As Long

On Error Resume Next

Set oDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olFolder = olNs.Session.PickFolder()

'Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

CategoryCnt = olNs.Categories.Count



ReDim arrData(1 To 2, 1 To CategoryCnt)

c = 0
For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
    If Not oDict.Exists(olItem.Categories) Then
        c = c + 1
        arrData(1, c) = olItem.Categories
        arrData(2, c) = 1
        oDict.Add olItem.Categories, c
    Else
        arrData(2, oDict.Item(olItem.Categories)) = arrData(2, oDict.Item(olItem.Categories)) + 1
    End If
Next olItem

ReDim Preserve arrData(1 To 2, 1 To c)

Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrData, 2), UBound(arrData, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(arrData)

MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Folder_Picker()

    'Needs reference to MS Outlook Object Library

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olParentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olFolderA As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olFolderB As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim Folder_name(100, 100) As String

Dim folder_count(100, 100) As String
     i = 1
     j = 1

Set olParentFolder = olNs.Session.PickFolder()

    For Each olFolderA In olParentFolder.Folders
        'Debug.Print olFolderA.folderPath, olFolderA.Items.Count, olFolderA.Folders.Count

         Folder_name(i, j) = olFolderA.folderPath
        folder_count(i, j) = olFolderA.Folders.Count

         j = j + 1
        For Each olFolderB In olFolderA.Folders
           ' Debug.Print olFolderB.folderPath, olFolderB.Items.Count

        Folder_name(i, j) = olFolderA.folderPath
        folder_count(i, j) = olFolderA.Folders.Count

         j = j + 1

        Next
        j = 1
        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @newjenn it looks like you're on the right lines as to what I'm after with the olParentFolder, but it's not outputting as I need it. For example each category in Outlook is who worked it and outputs to Excel with totals per category. To give something similar to below?                                                                      
Steve 6
John        1
Phil        1
Stu        1

Comment: Thanks, but I still think we're on two different tracks here... I'm talking about categories as in the colour categories within Excel, I don't quite understand what you are getting at with folderA & folderB?

Answer (score 0):

The PickFolder dialog cannot be customized to support checked treelist items ([Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) has this feature though).

Also, if you want to process all subfolders from any given folder, you need to do so recursively to ensure you get children of children all the way down the folder levels, like so:

```
Sub ProcessFolderCaller()
     Dim objInbox As Folder

     Set objInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
     ProcessFolder objInbox
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolder(objFolder As Folder)
     Dim intX As Integer
     Dim objSubFolders As Folders

     Debug.Print "Processing folder '" & objFolder.Name & "'..."

     Set objSubFolders = objFolder.Folders

     For intX = 1 To objSubFolders.Count
         Dim objSubjFolderA As Folder
         Set objSubjFolderA = objSubFolders.Item(intX)
         ProcessFolder objSubjFolderA
     Next
 End Sub
```